# Using Paypal Rest API with Node

Tags: node.js, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am having a problem debugging my paypal integration with Node and the rest api https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-nodejs

- I created a Paypal account
- I got the creditials for the app
- I created an app and set a password for a user
- I log into the sandbox with that user
- I don`t see any transaction history

The code snippet is as follows :

```
var config_opts = {
    'host': 'api.sandbox.paypal.com',
    'port': '',
    'client_id': 'my id',
    'client_secret': 'my secret'
 };

  var create_payment_json = {
    "intent": "sale",
    "payer": {
    "payment_method": "paypal"
},
"redirect_urls": {
    "return_url": "http://localhost:3000",
    "cancel_url": "http://localhost:3000"
},
"transactions": [{
    "amount": {
        "currency": "USD",
        "total": "10.00"
    },
    "description": "This is the payment description."
}]
  };

     paypal_sdk.payment.create(create_payment_json, config_opts, function (err, res) {
if (err) {
    console.log( err );
}

if (res) {
    console.log("Create Payment Response");
    console.log(res);
}  
 });
```

The response I get is as follows:

```
{ id: 'PAY-55J119327J2030636KLXMVJI',
  create_time: '2014-02-02T22:45:57Z',
  update_time: '2014-02-02T22:45:57Z',
  state: 'created',
  intent: 'sale',
  payer: 
   { payment_method: 'paypal',
     payer_info: { shipping_address: {} } },
  transactions: 
   [ { amount: [Object],
       description: 'This is the payment description.' } ],
  links: 
   [ { href: 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-  55J119327J2030636KLXMVJI',
       rel: 'self',
       method: 'GET' },
 {     href: 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-90D3081342725343U',
       rel: 'approval_url',
       method: 'REDIRECT' },
 {     href: 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-55J119327J2030636KLXMVJI/execute',
       rel: 'execute',
       method: 'POST' } ] }
```

I am wondering if there is some additional step in authenticating that I am missing ?

Comment: UPDATE: I can see my transactions on https://developer.paypal.com/ but not in my sandbox account. Have paypal changed how the sandbox works ?

Answer (score 3):

First, you have to declare a proper return_url (not just localhost:3000). I suggest that you change your return_url to "http://localhost:3000/success". Then, insert this one above your payment POST METHOD:

```js
app.get('/success', function(req, res) {
    var paymentId = req.query.paymentId;
    var payerId = { 'payer_id': req.query.PayerID };

    paypal.payment.execute(paymentId, payerId, function(error, payment){
        if(error){
            console.error(error);
        } else {
            if (payment.state === 'approved'){ 
                res.send('payment completed successfully');
                console.log(payment);
            } else {
                res.send('payment not successful');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

This GET method will execute your payment. But, before it can execute, you must redirect first your server's response to paypal sandbox for payment confirmation.

Edit the content of your paypal_sdk.payment.create() function like this one:

```js
paypal_sdk.payment.create(create_payment_json, config_opts, function (err, res) {
    if (err) {
       console.log( err );
    }

    else {
        console.log("Create Payment Response");
        console.log(res);

        //you forgot to redirect your response to paypal sandbox
        var redirectUrl;
        for(var i=0; i < payment.links.length; i++) {
            var link = payment.links[i];
            if (link.method === 'REDIRECT') {
                redirectUrl = link.href;
            }
        }
        res.redirect(redirectUrl);
    }  
});
```

I hope this can help (especially to those who are still looking for answers)

Comment: please help me out too, I managed to execute the transaction and temporary personal account shows that transaction but the merchant account doesn't show anything to approve it. temprory account shows that " This is a temporary authorization to make sure your payment method will cover the payment. Your payment method will be charged when jawad merchant's Test Store completes your order."

Comment: Here's the link to my question and code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52297388/paypal-rest-sdk-completes-the-transaction-but-waits-for-the-merchant-accounts-to

Answer (score 1):

You must go to Dashboard -> Rest API transactions.

See the attached screenshot:

[image]